# php while loop variable increase number

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a while loop that gathers information from my DB. I then echo that out like this...

```
$num = 1;
$i=0;
$drop = 'yes';
echo '<form id="drop_form" method="post" action="here.php">';

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

   $player[] = $row['player'];

   echo '<tr class="rows"><td>'; echo'<input type="hidden"
   name="yeah" value="'.$num.'"/>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>';

   echo $player[$i].'</td></tr>'; 

   $num++;                         
   $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
```

when I post my `$num` variable it always show up as the last possible number. So if there are 7 rows in that query then the number will be 7. I want to be able to click on the submit button and get the hidden value in the submit form.

```
Player 
mike    hidden number = 1
chris   hidden number = 2
jim     hidden number = 3
dan     hidden number = 4
```

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: You're generating a form with several inputs, all called `yeah`, with different values. When you post the form, the earlier ones will be over-written by later ones, so the only one actually submitted is the last one.

Comment: Your `{` and `}` don't match up.

Comment: ok thanks andrewsi... should i change the name of the inputs for each one?

Comment: @Ricky: Either that, or use `name="yeah[]"`.  That will post all the values as an array (`$_POST['yeah']` will be an array).

Comment: ok thank you. i will work with that. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need (as said above) one form for all players OR one form for each individual player. The last alternative is perhaps what suits better, in the case you do actions on only one specific player at once.

Comment: I doubt that you want values from 1 to ... 4 or whatever. Actually you only need a player-ID and some value (e.g. 1 for TRUE) for your whatever "yeah" thingy...

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting something like `yeah=1&yeah=2&yeah=3`... This is equivalent to the following PHP:

```
$_POST['yeah'] = 1;
$_POST['yeah'] = 2;
$_POST['yeah'] = 3;
```

From this you can see that the variable is being overwritten.

Try using `name="yeah[]"`, as this will result in an array, as follows:

```
$_POST['yeah'][] = 1;
$_POST['yeah'][] = 2;
$_POST['yeah'][] = 3;
```

Resulting in `Array(1,2,3);`

Answer (score 1):

Add this before the start of your while loop: `$player = array();`

You should always define arrays before a loop :)

Hope this helps! :)

**Also:**

1.Change `name="yeah"` to `name=yeah[]` as you want this input to be an array.
2.Move the submit button outside of the `while loop` as you should only need one of these.